# Каким образом из jquery можно получить данные элемента массива, зная его id?

Tags: jquery, массивы

Добрый день.

Есть массив:

```
mainlist = [
{
"id":"20",
"iName":"Молочный коктейль",
"iCena":"111",
"iDesc":"111",
"categorys_id":"1",
"created_at":"2014-12-13 14:17:25",
"updated_at":"2014-12-13 14:17:25",
"categorys":
{"id":"1","catName":"555","catSort":"2","catDesc":"5555","created_at":"2014-12-11 02:27:01","updated_at":"2014-12-11 07:00:44"}
},
{
"id":"21",
"iName":"Немолочный коктейль",
"iCena":"1",
"iDesc":"111",
"categorys_id":"4",
"created_at":"2014-12-13 14:18:31",
"updated_at":"2014-12-13 15:23:47",
"categorys":
{"id":"4","catName":"666","catSort":"1","catDesc":"Lorem i","created_at":"2014-12-11 06:59:15","updated_at":"2014-12-11 06:59:15"}
}
];
```

Вопрос в следующем: как, зная id некоторого элемента массива (но не массива сategorys), получить его остальные данные с помощью jquery?

К примеру, я знаю, что у меня есть елемент с id=20. Как получить остальные параметры, к примеру, iName, iDesc?

Comment: @Стас Сидорюк, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: @Стас Сидорюк, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Тут jQuery не нужен. Можно обойтись нативным JS:

```
arr = JSON.parse(json);
```

Так вы распарсите JSON. Потом перебором массива:

```
for(var i in arr) {
    if(arr[i].id == 20) {
        res = arr[i];
        break;
    }
}
```

Теперь в `res` у Вас хранится нужный объект. Чтобы обратиться к свойствам - `res.iCena`, например, где `iCena` это свойство объекта.

Comment: А есть проще метод, чтоб обойтись без отдельного парсинга?

Comment: @Стас Сидорюк, в вашем случае [можно обойтись без парсинга][1]

[1]:http://jsfiddle.net/MasterAlex/p3sLst8L/